# Android: Embedding a compressed image inside a PDF document

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation, png, jpeg

How to embed a compressed image (e.g. PNG, JPEG, etc.) in an Android PdfDocument?

When writing the image into the Page's canvas, it is encoded as a bitmap, instead I'd like to embed the image compressed as it is.

Comment: I suspect that you will need to use a different PDF generation approach than `PdfDocument`.

Comment: That would be ok, but I can't find any approach which offers such basic function

Comment: Without changing compression ratio, you can at least downscale. Take a look at my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47840875/3519951
With the built-in PDFDocument compression, I was able to achieve a satisfying file size.

Answer (score 0):

I've just realised I can do this with iText:
[itext images tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/image.html)

Unfortunately, it does not allow to draw views in a canvas like the native PdfDocument class. So I need to create a PDF without images with PdfDocument and put a placeholder for such images. Then I need to open the pdf file with iText and append the images at the placeholders' location.