# PDF creation using Android PdfDocument API - File size is too large

Tags: android, pdf

I try to make a PDF using the `PdfDocument` API. This is what I have tried :

```
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    // create a new document
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile, true);

    for (int i = 0; i < mImagePathList.size(); i++) {

        //current image path
        String imagePath = mImagePathList.get(i);

        //get a bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = createBitmap(imagePath); // This method returns a bitmap from path
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);

        // crate a page description
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), i + 1).create();

        // start a pagegit
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        // get the page canvas
        Canvas pdfCanvas = page.getCanvas();

        if (pdfCanvas != null) {

            // draw bitmap on the page
            //pdfCanvas.draw(d, 0, 0, paint);
            d.draw(pdfCanvas);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG " Canvas null!");
        }

        paint.reset();
        // finish the page
        document.finishPage(page);
    }

        // write the document content
        document.writeTo(fos);

        document.close();
        //publishProgress(i);
        fos.close();
```

I used a `Drawable` above just as an experiment which produced the same output as following code :

```
//get a bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = createBitmap(imagePath);
pdfCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null); //passing paint object instead of null have no effect
```

I have looked at many SO posts but most of them uses third-party libraries to solve this problem. I want to stick to Android's `PdfDocument`.

If I insert an image of 5MB, resulting PDF file size is 45MB. It usually multiplies by 10 or even 20 sometimes.

Comment: Can you scale down the bitmap when you read it in?  http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Scailing down does not help in this case. I tried the same code.

Comment: I have tried scaling down the image but it did not help. Problem is even if I take image as low as of original size 20Kb, the pdf generated is of around 600 to 900 kb. I also tried creating a pdf with blank canvas (No draw of Bitmap), the size of the PDF was 1-2Kb. It seems some issue with "drawBitmap" method, though I am not sure. Please suggest something.

Comment: I have the same probelm . The pdf is huge ! Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I've same proble. How do you resolve this issue?

Comment: In case anyone is still working on this and does not just want PdfDocument as the only option :https://stackoverflow.com/a/47192359/3121246. I was able to achieve much smaller PDF file size.